# What to do after activating Microsoft Office too many times?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-activation

I swap, replace, and upgrade my main workstation pretty often and over the last couple of years, have subsequently installed/reinstalled/reactivated my copy of Office several times and finally its telling me i can't activate.

So is that it?  I have to run out and buy another copy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had lots of luck activating over the phone.  They're usually willing to free up licenses if you explain that you've used them for reinstalling on one machine.

Answer (score 6):

Call and have them reset the activation counter. It's a cinch.

Comment: No need to take a dig at foreign based call centers.

Comment: You're right, I'm just bitter after having recently experienced some major problems doing this very thing. I'll edit it out.